# How to separate Chrome App windows in KDE Plasma 5?

Tags: kde, chrome, plasma5

I want to separate icons in a task bar for different Chrome Apps - no grouping as similar for Chrome, Music App, etc.

Also I want to switch between open windows per application (Alt + ` by default) - with a proper grouping per Chrome App.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work since Plasma 5.8, at least for Chrome but not for Chromium. You need to add the applications to desktop via the hamburger menu and check the "open in new window" checkbox.

**Update:** Since one of the last updates to Plasma this no longer works...

Comment: Same here. When I updated to Plasma 5.8.3 (from 5.8.1) the proper icon management was lost.